# How can I decrease a method count in my activity in MVP pattern?

Tags: android, mvp, android-mvp

I build my app in MVP architecture and I have a trouble with many functions in my activity and presenter. How Can I decrease a method count?

I have already heard about some solutions:

- Split a big presenter into smaller ones but then I would have to create another methods in my activity for presenters connection.
- Create a new class and create it instance in my activity which would implement the View interface and will require all of the views needed to manage the presenters. But I am not convinced to this solution. I think it may add another mess to my architecture.

Do you have other ideas or advantages/disadvantages about one described above?

Comment: why you want to reduce the number of methods? Can you share any code where do you think that some redundant methods are present.

Comment: Now my activity launches another activities, fragments, get permissions and activities results and do a lot of another basic activity operations . On the other hand it also updates the view from many View interface methods. I want to split that responsibility.

Comment: One option is, to manage views and bind UIcomponents with your code to avoid adding extra codes you can use Android Data Binding, here is the link
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#0

Comment: Thanks, It's great solution but require using a LiveData. For MVP it would decrease only count of invoking Presenter interface methods in activity

Answer (score 0):

There is more than a way to reduce methods from your **Activity/Fragment**

One is called **inheritance**, where you can extend abstract methods into your main **Activity/Fragment** class and manage the lifecycle from there.

For example, using **BaseActivity** or **BaseFragment** you can have more than one method inside of it and just extend that into your main `Activity` or `Fragment`

### BaseActivity.kt

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(getLayout())
}

@LayoutRes
abstract fun getLayout(): Int

fun Context.toast(message: String?, toastDuration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, toastDuration).show()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    //Do here what you want
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    //Do here what you want
}

override fun onStart(){
    super.onStart()
    //Do here what you want

}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    //Do here what you want
}

override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()
    //Do here what you want
}
```

}

This **BaseActivity** extends `AppCompatActivity()`, that means that you can manage the lifecycle of your `Activity` in this class, and then, just extend it in your main `Activity`, when you do this, all the functionality inside your **BaseActivity** will be applied to your `MainActivity` class, if you want to change or override something, just call the methods from that abstract class.

### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //You dont need setContentView since we do all the configuration in the BaseActivity
      toast("This is a message with a toast since we implemented thi into the BaseActivity we do not need to do toasts all over again")
    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_login_view
    }

//For example, if you want to override the functionallity from a method inside your BaseActivity you can implement it like always

 override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
        //Replace what BaseActivity onRestart() does
    }
```

Doing this, you can have more than 1 method of your `Activity` inside your **BaseActivity**, this will reduce the methods inside your class that inherits from **BaseActivity**, also, if you need this to work with `Fragments`, just extend `Fragment` instead of `AppCompatActivity` an make a class called **BaseFragment**

Also, adding an interface for view operations and presenter operations is a great way to organize our apps, you can take a look at an example I'm making for login on [Github](https://github.com/gastsail/CleanFirestoreLogin)